# Extract Email address from a digital signature in pdf using itext7

Tags: c#, email, pdf, itext, certificate

Given a pdf is signed using DSC token certificate. Adobe reader gives the email address of the user to who has signed.How can i extract email address from digital signature using itext7 c#?

I have tried to extract data in PdfPKCS7 class.But it does not contain email address.

Using ItextSharp,

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
AcroFields fields = reader.AcroFields;
List<String> names = fields.GetSignatureNames();
foreach (string name in names)
{
   VerifySignature(fields, name);
}
```

Where verify Signature method gives certificate details

```
 virtual public PdfPKCS7 VerifySignature(AcroFields fields, String name)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Signature covers whole document: " + fields.SignatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
    Console.WriteLine("Document revision: " + fields.GetRevision(name) + " of " + fields.TotalRevisions);
    PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.VerifySignature(name);
    Console.WriteLine("Integrity check OK? " + pkcs7.Verify());
    return pkcs7;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried?. show your code

Comment: *"Given a pdf is signed using DSC token certificate."* - Please share an example to allow reproducing the issue. ... *"Adobe reader gives the email address of the user to who has signed"* - Where? ... *[tag:dsc] tag* - Desired State Configuration (DSC), is that really what you mean by DSC?

Comment: what i mean to say is when you open the same document in adobe reader , it gives the email address along with certificate details i.e. Signature is VALID, signed by abc <abc@abcd.in>

Comment: no dsc is digital signature certificate

Comment: *"dsc is digital signature certificate"* - in that case you shouldn't use the [tag:dsc] as it is meant for "Desired State Configuration" as you can see hovering over it. ... *"signed by abc <abc@abcd.in>"* - that looks like it's the common name of the signer certificate subject. You should inspect the signer certificate of the signature. You can retrieve it from the `PdfPKCS7` object. For more details, please share an example PDF to run example code against here.

Comment: how can i retrieve it from PdfPKCS7 object? I found no field indicative of email address in it.

Comment: For more details, please share an example PDF to run example code against here.

Comment: U may find a sample pdf attached. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_38jjUQuCi6H_ecZ70Wuid5rdW5ERMJn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For this particular document the email can be found in the /Name entry of the signature dictionary

Comment: I understand , it is because in this example pdf the name and email id are same.But what i m looking for is how to get the emailId field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example PDF contains the email address in at least four locations:

- The **Name** entry of the signature value.
- The subject alternative name of the signer certificate.
- The common name of the subject DN of the signer certificate.
- The email address of the subject DN of the signer certificate.

The following code corresponds to your iTextSharp code plus the output of the four email address locations:

```cs
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(PDF))
using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader))
{
    SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
    foreach (string signatureName in signatureUtil.GetSignatureNames())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n{0}\n**********", signatureName);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + signatureUtil.GetSignature(signatureName).GetName());
        Console.WriteLine("Signature covers whole document: " + signatureUtil.SignatureCoversWholeDocument(signatureName));
        Console.WriteLine("Document revision: " + signatureUtil.GetRevision(signatureName) + " of " + signatureUtil.GetTotalRevisions());
        PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = signatureUtil.ReadSignatureData(signatureName);
        Console.WriteLine("Integrity check OK? " + pkcs7.VerifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity());
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = pkcs7.GetSigningCertificate();
        Console.Write("Subject alternative names: ");
        foreach (var list in cert.GetSubjectAlternativeNames())
            foreach (var name in (IList)list)
                Console.Write(name + " ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.X509Name subjectDn = cert.SubjectDN;
        Console.WriteLine("Subject DN: " + subjectDn);
        Console.Write("Subject DN common name: ");
        foreach (var name in subjectDn.GetValueList(Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.X509Name.CN))
            Console.Write(name + " ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Subject DN email: ");
        foreach (var name in subjectDn.GetValueList(Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.X509Name.EmailAddress))
            Console.Write(name + " ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The output for your file:

```
Signature1
**********
Name: gerald.holmann@qoppa.com
Signature covers whole document: True
Document revision: 1 of 1
Integrity check OK? True
Subject alternative names: 1 gerald.holmann@qoppa.com 
Subject DN: CN=gerald.holmann@qoppa.com,E=gerald.holmann@qoppa.com
Subject DN common name: gerald.holmann@qoppa.com 
Subject DN email: gerald.holmann@qoppa.com
```

I obviously cannot tell which of these positions will be used by other certificates you'll come across. Thus, you either have to find out whether that is specified somewhere in your requirements or you may have to simply check all these fields.

Adobe Reader at the position you pointed out most likely shows the common name of the subject DN of the signer certificate, but this needn't be an email address, it can be anything that serves as a *common name* for the certificate owner.

Comment: I got he required email id in Subject alternative names. Thanks Alot.

Comment: How can I extract telephone number?Its is encrypted..I've the below data :
SubjectDN: C=IN,O=Personal,PostalCode=*******,ST=****,TelephoneNumber=8ff48ed758c89647c947580f5fd6214071a43214964af89a1f120ac9b71d0b4d,