# How to get information of Digital signature in C# using iText7

Tags: c#, certificate, itext7

I am getting all the information of Digital Signature in C# using iTextSharp. Need same data related to Digital signature using iText7.

```cs
PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = VerifySignature(fields, name);

Console.WriteLine("Digest algorithm: " + pkcs7.GetHashAlgorithm());
Console.WriteLine("Encryption algorithm: " + pkcs7.GetEncryptionAlgorithm());
Console.WriteLine("Filter subtype: " + pkcs7.GetFilterSubtype());
X509Certificate cert = pkcs7.SigningCertificate;
Console.WriteLine("Name of the signer: " + CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields(cert).GetField("CN"));
if (pkcs7.SignName != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Alternative name of the signer: " + pkcs7.SignName);
```

Comment: What have you tried, what blocks you? After all, the iText7 `PdfPKCS7` class also has methods `GetHashAlgorithm`, `GetEncryptionAlgorithm`, `GetFilterSubtype`, and `GetSignName` and the `SigningCertificate` property has been replaced by a method `GetSigningCertificate`...

Comment: You are right. I tried this , it works.using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader))
            {
                SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdf);
                var c = signatureUtil.GetSignatureNames();
                foreach(var x in c)
                {
                    var ff = signatureUtil.ReadSignatureData(x);
                }
            } I am however getting all the information except email id associated with the digital signature.How can get that?

Comment: There is not necessarily an email address associated with a digital signature, and if one is, it can be so in a number of ways. Thus, please share a representative example signed pdf to analyze.

Comment: My question is well represented in the following question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474960/extract-email-address-from-a-digital-signature-in-pdf-using-itext7 . Sample pdf is also given.

Comment: See my answer there. In that question it was not clear where you read the information you're after. Here you show it's the common name of the subject DN of the signer certificate. Use the common name related code lines from the answer there.